# how to make my keyboard work again?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, trackpad, ubuntu-drivers

I have a chromebook that is running 14.04 and I was trying to get the trackpad to work so I tried the following:

```
mkdir ~/backup
sudo mv /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/* ~/backup/
cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
sudo wget http://craigerrington.com/chrome/x_al...
sudo unzip x_alarm_chrubuntu.zip
sudo rm x_alarm_chrubuntu.zip
```

then I checked my keyboard layout

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.c­onf
```

which was how it's supposed to be so I closed without saving, rebooted and now neither my keyboard or mouse work.

It boots to the log in screen and wont let me type my password or move mouse, same issue with external mouses/ keyboards. I can't even get into a virtual terminal.

This is my only computer and right now I'm using a live CD of kali, both the mouse and keyboard work fine in kali.

Is there a way to fix the issue in Ubuntu while I'm using kali?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with kali, but you should still have your Ubuntu CD lying around.  Boot into that, take the "try Ubuntu" option and you'll end up with a working version of Ubuntu with your Computer's volumes as icons on the launcher.

Click on the volumes containing your ~/ and your /usr (Depending on your installation this might be one and the same volume) and note the directory they're mounted on in the Ubuntu live system.

From a terminal, type:

```
cp /media/SomeWeirdNumber/home/YourUserName/backup/* /media/SomeWeirdNumner/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

reboot the machine from the system settings and you should be back where you were before you started messing with X11!  ;-)

Comment: dont have ubuntu cd/usb i installed ubuntu through a script, ima try moving the x11 files from kali into the ubuntu and hope they work, because i can access all of ubuntu's system stuff from kali

Comment: **No, don't move the ones from Kali!**  Just use Kali to boot and mount the Ubuntu stuff and use it to copy from your Ubuntu back-up into your Ubuntu Settings!!!

Comment: no back up, already moved the ones from kali and they're working fine, they are configuration files and such. cant use kali to boot/mount ubuntu because i have to shutdown kali to use ubuntu, but couldnt used ubuntu because no typing. now i can type because o copied kalis configuration files for the x11 stuff

Comment: Like I said: I don't know anything about the Kali distribution, and if you do and it works, I'd appreciate you accepting my answer and upvoting it, so that the next user around will find this answer helpful too!  ;-)